# Microsoft Excel - How to cumulatively add a range of values with a changing reference cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

This is not very easy to explain, so let try using an example:

[image: Picture]

Basically, I want to cumulative sum the range of values in column C if the values belong to the same category (in column A).

The problem I'm facing is that I need to change the reference cell from C$2 (used as the reference to cumulatively sum the values belonging to 'A') to C$5 to cumulatively sum all the values belonging to 'B'.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: In the picture, the formula I use for D2 is `=IF(A2=A1,SUM(C$1:$C2),C2)`.   This works perfectly until D5, after which it falls apart because instead of changing the reference cell to $C5, it continues to be linked to $C2. Hence all values after D6 go wrong...

Comment: Try SUMIF() this should do what you need

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The issue with a sumif () is I'm not sure how to change the reference cell. In the picture for example, the formula I use for D2 is "=IF(A2=A1,SUM(C$1:$C2),C2)". This works perfectly until D5, after which it falls apart because instead of changing the reference cell to $C5, it continues to be linked to $C2. Hence all values after D6 go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUMIF` and cleverly mix relative and absolute references:

`=SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2)`

[image]

Comment: Very elegant solution, just hadn't thought of this. Thanks

Comment: @NPJobs if this did the trick, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post